# magento 2 independet pagination on a single page

Tags: php, magento-1.7

On a category page I want to display 2 different type of products from the same category with pagination.

I would like to place 2 independent pagination on a single page, so URL should be something like this: `?p=2&p2=4` to not influence each other. Will be 2 product collections, for one(let it be main) I want to display toolbar in classic way: `<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>;` block object will write 1 collection which pager will use; But how about second productCollerction? how to add pagination to it and not rewrite first one, and how to change parameter in url from `p` to `p2` teach each pagination object to work with his own param. Hope I explain my issue good enough and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To create 2 independent navigations you should dublicate all blocks related to navigations(place than in app/local) and rename them to be different from official one:

and change value of $_GET['p'] in pages files. This worked for me.
Thank you for responces :)

Answer (score 0):

To have 2 pagination on single page

- update the url look like `p=2&p2=4`
- use function name `setPageVarName('p2')` of `\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager` class
- check parameter :
  `if  ($this->getRequest()->getParam('p'))` -> query first collection
  `else if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('p2')` -> query for second collection